# jquery css method putting wrong values when called often

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm trying to create my own jquery image carousel in order to make myself more acquainted with it.

You can find the example [here](http://pelloponisos.telesto.gr/galleryTest/gallery.php).

The carousel works by sliding the whole  right,  putting the last

before the first and sliding it back to hide the last.

Problem is if someone spams the next/prev button the whole carousel is moved to the right something not happening if the prev/next is used once per second or I set it to be clicked by jquery with a quick interval(500) for example.

the relevant parts of the code are:

```
function initUl(){
    var li_width = $('.upper li').outerWidth();
    var upper_width=$('.upper').outerWidth();
    var lower_width=$('.lower').outerWidth();
    var upper_pos = $('.upper').position();
    var lower_pos = $('.lower').position();

    lastBeforeFirst();

    $('.upper').css({'left': upper_pos.left + (-1*li_width)});
    $('.lower').css({'left': lower_pos.left + (-1*li_width)});
    $('.upper').css({'width': upper_width + li_width});
    $('.lower').css({'width': lower_width + li_width});
   }

function moveBothRight(){
    var speed = 200;
    var li_width = $('.upper li').outerWidth();
    var upper_pos = $('.upper').position();
    var lower_pos = $('.lower').position();

    $('.upper').animate({'left' :upper_pos.left + li_width}, speed,fixUpperPosR);
    $('.lower').animate({'left' :lower_pos.left + li_width}, speed,fixLowerPosR);   
   }

   function fixUpperPosR(){
    var li_width = $('.upper li').outerWidth();
    var upper_pos = $('.upper').position();

    $('.upper').css({'left': upper_pos.left - li_width});
    }

    function fixLowerPosR(){
    lastBeforeFirst();
    var li_width = $('.upper li').outerWidth();
    var lower_pos = $('.lower').position();

    $('.lower').css({'left': lower_pos.left - li_width});
     }
     function lastBeforeFirst(){

var first = $('.upper ul li:first');
var last = $('.upper ul li:last');

$(first).before($(last));

first = $('.lower ul li:first');
last = $('.lower ul li:last');
$(first).before($(last));
     }
```

This piece of code is responsible for moving everything right and its called on the next click the only difference on left is

```
$('.lower').css({'left': lower_pos.left + li_width});
```

and the firstBeforeLast(); call

Is this a browser thing(it cant update the css that quick) and therefore I should put a restriction on how often one can push the buttons, or i'm missing something?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle? and have you simply tried calling `.stop()` before `.animate()`?

Comment: no I havent and now it works great :D thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that animations are run asynchronously.

You need to [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the current animation and `jumpToEnd` whenever a button is clicked.

For example:

```
$('.upper').stop(true, true).animate(...);
```

This will cause the current animation to complete immediately and update the css as needed.